# What are the most useful habits or tasks I can get my family to do?

Tags: virtual-families

What are the best tasks to get my family to do?

I'm at the earliest stage of the game - and I've picked up all the wrappers and socks etc. I'm getting them to work on their careers and do homework... weeding... picking up collectibles... and praising them for working out and emptying the bins!

Any hints tips or advice?